# How to get the name of one table using the id in another table, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. `booking_details` and `vehicle_details`. 
in `booking_details`, `V_ID` is the foreign key and I want to fetch the `V_name` column from `Vehicle-details` with a particular user login. Please help me guys. tell me how could I solve this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM booking_details 
Join vehicle_detail 
on booking_details.V_Id = vehicle_detail.V_Id 
ORDER BY vehicle_detail.V_Name ASC
```

I tried this query. it will fetch both the values but I don't know how to put the where condition in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM booking_details
Join vehicle_detail
    on booking_details.V_Id = vehicle_detail.V_Id 
WHERE (...)
ORDER BY vehicle_detail.V_Name ASC
```